# Is Java ReDos vulnerable?

Tags: java, regex, security, java-11

I tried to recreate [regular expression denial of service attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS) using `(a+)+` regexp and `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!` (with large amounts of `a`) input using jshell:

```
Pattern.compile("(a+)+")
    .matcher("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!")
    .matches()
```

But this completes pretty quickly each time I tried. Is the regexp implementation in Java different from others? Or the linked wikipedia page is wrong?

(BTW. I'm using Java 11, if that's relevant)

EDIT: Looks like it is Java version related, when I tried it on Java 8, it hangs, but in Java 9 and 11 it works right away. What did change between those versions that could affect that? Are all regex safe now in Java?

Is there a specific Java JEP that changed the regexp implementation? I would like to know what kind of regexps are still a problem for newer Java.

Comment: If you have not seen it already: http://blog.mgm-tp.com/2012/06/regexp-java-puzzler-2/

Comment: @PM77-1 I tried the code from that page and it works fast also, and prints the results as described there.

Comment: Your pattern is fine with most of the regex engines. The only problem with this kind of patterns is when it is followed with some other patterns.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not really. Java’s engine might have become a bit better, but just changing it to `((a+)+)+` makes it hang again. And it can be proven that each additional nesting, i.e. `(((a+)+)+)+`, `((((a+)+)+)+)+` raises the complexity, so Java’s engine has not learned to cope with this pattern, it just became a bit better at nested iterations.

Comment: @Holger Try `(a)(\1*)+x`. I doubt that many engines has protection against repeating patterns from backreferences. Though it is not a common pattern.

Comment: The following will hang in Java 17: `Pattern.compile("(.*a){10000}").matcher("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!").matches();`

Comment: FYI, more recent versions of Java seem to be immune to the patterns suggested by Holger .  The patterns suggested by inf3rno and xonya still cause it to hang tho.  (I needed an example of this for a unit test, and the test was passing in one version of Java but failing on the next lol. @inf3rno's example got my test working again tho, thanks!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the article [RSPEC-2631](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2631), the ReDoS issue has been handled in Java 9 and later:

> Java runtimes like OpenJDK 9+ are mitigating this problem by having additional protections in their implementation of regular expression evaluation. In those runtime the example above is not vulnerable.

Comment: Java 9+ is still vulnerable to ReDoS, just needs trickier patterns than `(a|aa)+`. See comments elsewhere; this is for those who just look at the accepted answer. This problem certainly will never go away. RE2, a regular expression engine, is by design immune to these exponential runtime problems, but they had to drop certain regular expression features for this (compared to Java/Perl regular expressions).

Answer (score 2):

I am currently running Java 8 and the following code hangs:

```
Pattern.compile("(a|aa)+")
       .matcher("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab")
       .matches()
```

Seeing as how you are using Java 11 (and have also tested it with Java 9/10) and have seen it take a small amount of time to complete, there was obviously a change that was made between those versions.

From looking at the source code of `Matcher` in Java 11, we find the following addition that isn't present in Java 8:

```
/**
 * Storage used by top greedy Loop node to store a specific hash set to
 * keep the beginning index of the failed repetition match. The nodes
 * themselves are stateless, so they rely on this field to hold state
 * during a match.
 */
IntHashSet[] localsPos;
```

This local storage, along with a large amount of other code added, seems to be one of the main reasons why the state machine for regular expressions in Java 9+ completes much faster than in Java 8 and below.

Comment: Again, it completed in under a second (and returned `false`)

Comment: @KrzysztofKrasoń What happens if you don't use JShell to run it?

Comment: It behaves the same, fast execution on Java 11, but on Java 8 it hangs like described above.

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into this more when I have access to a machine that I can install other versions on. In the meantime, it would be useful to check if `9` and `10` are any different.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, this is an interesting find! I'll keep you updated with anything else that I discover.

Comment: IMO, this currently doesn't answer the question. Neither is it adding any additional information to the same. :|

Comment: @nullpointer It seems that way since OP edited the question after I answered stating that the issue is version-specific.